# Nunit3: how to save the test results while tests are running via Console Runner

Tags: nunit-3.0, nunit-console

NUnit3 Console runner saves test results in xml at the end of the test run. But in my case I want to save the partial results on each test failure, so that in case console runner crashes or is stopped, I can still get partial results for completed tests.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Test Results are saved regardless of failures or successful test runs. The XML file is generated for every test run. You could also write every test result to a log file if the XML is not generated for a particular test run.